# Cannot get an accessToken from LinkedIn API due to 'redirect_uri' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to achieve LinkedIn sign in using their API provided by Oauth2.0
According to docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/consumer/context

I am able to get access code (1 step). Afterwards I stuck on completing new request with error (to get an accessToken) - https://gyazo.com/abe24d7294aa4c1b9d8be9a101747ee2

Although I did configure my redirect URI in LinkedIn dev dashboard - https://gyazo.com/c533a589465042342d79438eab02d2a2

I've tried `querystring.stringify` method from `query-string` package

```
function trigerLogin() {
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('AccessCode');
  if (!accessToken) {
    window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&state=DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424&client_id=*************&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000%2Fcallback&scope=r_liteprofile+r_emailaddress', '_blank', 'top=100, left=200, height=500, width=500');
  }
  axios.post('https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken', querystring.stringify({
    client_id: '*************', // for safety reasons
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: accessToken,
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4000/callback',
    client_secret: '**************' // for safety reasons
  }))
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {console.log(error)})
  }
```

So I cannot get a response with a token with which I can work further

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @CameronDowner I am making an initial request inside `if` block.

Comment: Yeah sorry, missed that. Have you checked that `accessToken` / `AccessCode` is being set correctly from the callback?

Comment: @CameronDowner good catch! I messed up with setting the code with wrong queries :). Thank you a lot !